# visualization calender python

Tags: python, calendar, visualization

Data visualization (python preferred but not essential):

I have some data which fits into daily chunks nicely for a period of a few months, how may I produce an infographic/calender-type graph analogous to this (found online):

[image]

My preferred medium is Python (would htmlCalender suffice?) but anything to accomplish this will be fine.

Comment: jonrsharp, this was supposed to be broad by design, a preferred method was python to achieve this goal (shown clearly graphically) otherwise other languages may be used - or even a package. Feel free to edit if you find this unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you take a look at [D3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3).

If you look at the examples there is a [Calendar View](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318) that does something closely to what you want to accomplish.

Another example of a similar calendar visualization is [Cal-heatmap](http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/).

You will find more libraries with similar concepts if you google for "calendar heatmap".